# Express Checkout for Paypal, why three methods to complete a payment?

Tags: php, paypal

I dont get it.

As of my knowledge currently, there is three must-have methods in order to complete a complete transaction.

1. SetExpressCheckout
   Makes sense, I create a payment with the items in it and all, then redirect the user to the redirecturi i receive in the response.
2. GetExpressCheckoutDetails
   This method should be on the url that is specified on the returnurl from the SetExpressCheckout. By getting the TOKEN that comes from paypal and use it for calling this method, we can get Payer ID, that we will use to call the final method DoExpressCheckoutPayment
3. DoExpressCheckoutPayment
   This method requires a TOKEN and PAYER ID that we now both have. It also requires the Payment and the payment items, to really complete the transaction.

Now my questions are:

1. On my returnurl, I am calling both GetExpressCheckoutDetails and then DoExpressCheckoutPayment. Now - can I always go out from that everything is correct and the transaction WILL go through when calling these two? I am thinking, maybe Paypal doesnt continue to the returnurl if the user has insufficient funds ?
2. Why do we need to specify the payment items all again in DoExpressCheckoutPayment ? When we already did it in SetExpressCheckout?

I am so used to other payment gateways that simply have an initiation of the payment -> redirect to payment gateway -> complete. Where they then make an callback when the transaction is really completed and then I can set the order to completed and deliver items to the user.

I hope someone can clarify things up for me, once and for all (there's so many similiar questions regarding this)

Update

```
$DECPFields = array(
                    'token' => $_GET['token'],                              // Required.  A timestamped token, the value of which was returned by a previous SetExpressCheckout call.
                    'payerid' => $_GET['PayerID'],                          // Required.  Unique PayPal customer id of the payer.  Returned by GetExpressCheckoutDetails, or if you used SKIPDETAILS it's returned in the URL back to your RETURNURL.
                    'returnfmfdetails' => '1',                  // Flag to indiciate whether you want the results returned by Fraud Management Filters or not.  1 or 0.                         'allowedpaymentmethod' => 'InstantPaymentOnly',                 // The payment method type. Specify the value InstantPaymentOnly.
                    'buttonsource' => '',                       // ID code for use by third-party apps to identify transactions in PayPal. 
                    'USESESSIONPAYMENTDETAILS' => '1'
                );

$PayPalRequest = array(
                       'DECPFields' => $DECPFields
                       );

$decp = $PayPal -> DoExpressCheckoutPayment($PayPalRequest);
```

This is the request/response

```
Array
(
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2014-04-13T00:14:26Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => 7f6dd4f8798aa
    [ACK] => Failure
    [VERSION] => 112.0
    [BUILD] => 10567876
    [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10400
    [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details.
    [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => Order total is missing.
    [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
    [ERRORS] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [L_ERRORCODE] => 10400
                    [L_SHORTMESSAGE] => Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details.
                    [L_LONGMESSAGE] => Order total is missing.
                    [L_SEVERITYCODE] => Error
                )

        )

    [PAYMENTS] => Array
        (
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you explained about other payment gateways is essentially what [PayPal Payments Standard](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/wp_standard_overview/) is.  A very basic HTML form that sends the user over to the gateway where they sign in or enter cc details to complete the payment and it's done.  Then you could setup [IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/) to receive data about that transaction and automate post-processing tasks like you mentioned.

[Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/) is more advanced.  It uses the actual API's and provides a lot more freedom to integrate things exactly how you want to suit your needs.

First, GetExpressCheckoutDetails is optional.  When you call SetExpressCheckout and then redirect to PayPal you can use the "useraction" parameter on that redirect URL to change the experience.  If you use useraction=commit then two things will happen.

- The button on the PayPal review page will change from "Continue" to "Pay"
- The PayerID will be returned as a URL parameter when PayPal sends the user back to your site.  This allows you to skip straight to DoExpressCheckoutPayment if you want to.

As part of that feature, you can also [setup a callback that communicates with PayPal's review page](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECInstantUpdateAPI/).  Their review page will POST the buyer's shipping address and item details back to your script.  Your script can take that data, calculate shipping options with it, and return the shipping and tax details back to the PayPal review page.  The PayPal page updates a drop down list that gets populated with the results your script returns so the user can complete the entire order using the PayPal review and you don't need to build another review on your own site.

As for DoExpressCheckoutPayment, if you include the [USESESSIONPAYMENTDETAILS](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoExpressCheckoutPayment_API_Operation_NVP/#usesessionpaymentdetails) parameter in that request it will use the details you sent with SetExpressCheckout so you don't have to include it all again.

Something could indeed go wrong with GECD and DECP, so you always want to run through error handling and log accordingly.  There are instances where the funding that was chosen on the PayPal page doesn't work, and [PayPal actually builds in a way to circle back around and handle that](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec_fundingfailure10486/) based on a particular error code you'd get back.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Lets say I dont use useraction=commit - what have paypal thought? Create order -> redirect to paypal -> going back to merchant site for reviewing the order? (but isnt express checkout so that you dont go back to merchants shop until youre completly done?) - because i still dont understand the getExpressCheckoutDetails part, why its there

Comment: The regular flow would consist of the user being sent to PayPal to login or enter cc details, then review the order and click continue.  That's when they'd be sent back to your site.  You would use GECD to obtain the shipping address so you can calculate shipping/tax that might need to be applied and display a final review page to your buyer prior to calling DECP to finalize the whole thing.

Comment: Very good explanations! So I went with having useraction=commit, so I can call DoExpressCheckoutPayment directly when it fails even though I have USESESSIONPAYMENTDETAILS and token, payerid provided: Order total is missing?

Comment: Please check my updated answer code. When it should use the payment details from setexpress, i should not specify total in this request ?

Comment: I am having an basket overview before the whole paypal start, where tax and shipping gets calculated correctly. Then I send the data of the customer with paypal and its all filled out so they can pay directly with card / login. But should I on the SetExpressCheckout, receive the token - save it with the order and then at the DoExpressCheckout grab the order and provide the total? But what I can see in the docs, order total is only for payment request -- which it should grab from usesessionpaymentdetails , which leaves me unanswered

Comment: It's a new parameter that I really haven't tested much myself.  It may be that you need to include the total in DECP but you could leave all of the individual item details, shipping, etc. off.  Also, what API version are you sending in the request?  It's a new parameter so I'd make sure to use version 112.0

Comment: Checked I was running 97.0 (I actually use your library, very nice btw), changed that to version 112 - still nothing. I cant figure out the order total is missing? There is no field to fill the total in the DECP fields (besides the payment requests? but then it makes no sense, usessionpaymentdetails will have no function)

Comment: Updated answer with the response

Comment: Glad to hear you're using the library and liking it.  Have you tried including the total amount and leaving everything else off of DECP to see if it works then?

Comment: Yes, or, I have tried to make add one Payment request to "Payments" in  (without items) to it with filled parametres amt, itemamt, shippingamt and taxamt (which are the only ones that could be the total amount?) - still same error message.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/UnDgM8iK -- So I guess I'll do the complicated way and re-do the payment with payment items for the DECP action?

Comment: Well, yeah, that way does work for sure, and it's not all that complicated.  Since you're doing it already in SEC it's basically a copy/paste to do it again in DECP.  Especially if you're using my library.

Comment: I'm new to pay pal and getting nowhere fast. I to dont understand their process and can't get it working, can you recommend any other payment gateways that are less hassle

Comment: All payment gateways are going to be similar.  PayPal just has a lot more products than others, so that can be confusing.  What exactly are you needing?  Just a basic payment button, or more advanced integration into a custom system of some sort?